# How to get nested js selectors like td?

Tags: javascript

I need to get all selector that match the condition so I can iterate thru it later on. My code does not return any values. Probably syntax is wrong so I would appreciate if you help me (haven't written lots in js).

Here is the html

[image: html]

```
function restore_hp(){

    var percent_restore = document.querySelectorAll("table.table.table-condensed.table-top-spacing > tr > td[2]");
    percent_restore.forEach((td)=>{
        console.log(td.innerText)
    });

}
```

Comment: *Here is the html* - **No.** "Here is an image of the html".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is something called `:nth-child` pseudo selector. Learn more from the below link-
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

SO your function may be like-

```
function restore_hp(){

    var percent_restore = document.querySelectorAll("table.table.table-condensed.table-top-spacing  tr td:nth-child(2)");
    percent_restore.forEach((td)=>{
        console.log(td.innerText)
    });

}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ashfaq_haq/pen/WNNOYRR

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for `td:nth-child(2)` at the end of your selector.

Your current `td[2]` would select such a table cell: `<td 2="some-attribute-value">...</td>`. Notice that this would be invalid HTML because a) `2` is an invalid attribut identifier (cannot start with a number) and b) even if it in general would be valid syntax it wouldn't be known for `HTMLTableCellElement`, and thus again, invalid HTML.

2nd issue:

`>` selects direct children only. `tr` is not a direct child of your `table` (it never is, missing `tbody` is auto-inserted by all browsers).

Comment: I tried your solution changin my selector to table.table.table-condensed.table-top-spacing > tr > td:nth-child(2) and at least I do not receive the error but values neither :(

Comment: `>` selects **direct** children only. `tr` is not a direct child of your `table` (it never is, missing `tbody` is auto-inserted by all browsers).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a HTML class to the elements you want to manipulate and simply query on the class :

```
...
<tr>
  <td>Some text</td>
  <td class="my-custom-class">Some other text</td>
</tr>
...
```

```
var percent_restore = document.querySelectorAll(".my-custom-class");
percent_restore.forEach((td)=>{
    console.log(td.innerText)
});
```

That way you're not lost in your HTML tree.

Comment: I'm working on automation website so manipulating the html is not a good idea. I need to work on original one.